# How to pass order ID to Paypal Button?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I create an order by my php sdk.

like this

```
$result = json_decode((string) $response->getBody());

echo $result->id; // id of the created order
```

and now i have this order id. but ... How to pass order ID to Paypal Button?
like this

```
`paypal.Buttons({

    // Set up the transaction
    createOrder: function(data, actions) { //I don't need create order,I have created an order
        return actions.order.create({
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    value: '88.44'
                }
            }]
        });
    },

    // Finalize the transaction
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
            // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
            console.log('Capture result', orderData, JSON.stringify(orderData, null, 2));
            var transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
            alert('Transaction '+ transaction.status + ': ' + transaction.id + '\n\nSee console for all available details');

            // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
            // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
            // element.innerHTML = '';
            // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
            // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
        });
    }


}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two routes on your server, one to create an order (and return the resulting JSON), and one that takes an order id as a parameter and captures it (and returns the JSON result).

**Both of these routes should return/output only JSON (no HTML or text).**

Pair those two routes with this approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Can you be more specific? what do i need in php? Is there a demo that I can refer to?

Comment: The PayPal Checkout documentation https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ has a full stack example, usng node.js for the backend. That backend can of course be implemented in any environment capable of doing the API calls and returning JSON when called -- including PHP of course. There is a Checkout-PHP-SDK you can use if desired. (Do not use the deprecated PayPal-PHP-SDK)

Comment: I have learnt it! I'm done! Love U!@